# How To Use Pupeteer To Get The Value Of A Hidden Input Tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, steam

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)

    const element = await page.waitForSelector('input[type="hidden"][name="abuseID"]', {
        hidden: true,
        timeout: 15000
    })

    const abuseID = await page.evaluate(element => element.value, element)

    console.log(abuseID)
}

scrapeProduct('https://steamcommunity.com/id/lupusRe')
```

I don't know where I am going wrong but I am getting an error of

```
file:///C:/Users/charl/Desktop/Code/abg/steam-search/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:282
        throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
              ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:21
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (file:///C:/Users/charl/Desktop/Code/abg/steam-search/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:282:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (file:///C:/Users/charl/Desktop/Code/abg/steam-search/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:114:16)
    at async scrapeProduct (file:///C:/Users/charl/Desktop/Code/abg/steam-search/test.js:13:21)
```

My goal is to be able to get the steam ID in the below tag
[<input type="hidden" name="abuseID" value="76561198036553525>"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JANOe.png)

I am open to using other things beside puppeteer but its just the main thing that I have been using for web scraping.

This is on the official steam community website if that matters.

Comment: try using Xpath of the element

Comment: @Mordor, have you got an example for how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Copy Xpath of an element 
[image]

and use `page.$x(Xpath)`

Edit: i've tried couple of things and it seems like you can get persons steamID through a `<script>` tag

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url);
    const text = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script'), element => element.textContent));
    let spl = text[38].split(',');
    console.log(spl[1])
    browser.close()
}

scrapeProduct('https://steamcommunity.com/id/DaYanack')
```

try this and tell me if it works

Comment: yeah I have tried that but the variable I am assigning it to just keeps returning as undefined, not sure if it means that the xpath is wrong or something else.

Comment: i updated the answer it works perfectly fine for me, give it a shot